# Select listitem from listbox in xaml

Tags: c#, listbox, windows-phone-8.1

I have a listbox,the data in listbox is getting populated through sqlite database.

**XAML**

[image]

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBoxobj" Background="Transparent" Margin="6" Height="auto" BorderThickness="2" MaxHeight="580" Grid.Row="1" SelectionChanged="listBoxobj_SelectionChanged">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Width="330" Height="100" >
                <Border Margin="5" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <CheckBox Name="Option1CheckBox" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" IsChecked="{Binding _isComplete}"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="NameTxt" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="22" Foreground="White"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="Age" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="White" FontSize="22" Text="{Binding Age}" />
                        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" x:Name="deleteTaskButton" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0"  Click="deleteTaskButton_Click" Height="18">
                            <Image Source="/Assets/delete.png"/>
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

When the user clicks on deleteTaskButton which is present in each listitem,the listboxitem data should get deleted from the list and move to another list present in next Pivot page.How can I do that?
When I click on the delete button the list is not getting selected but the delete icon is selected.

Comment: What does your `deleteTaskButton_Click()` method look like?

Answer (score 0):

So as there was no information on the data types of the data contained in the listview. I've written down how your `deleteTaskButton_Click` method should look. Replace `YourDataType` with your data type and `secondListBoxobj` with the name of the second `listbox`

```
 private void deleteTaskButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dataContext = (sender as Button).DataContext as YourDataType;
        if (dataContext != null)
        {
            //now you have the item that was clicked to delete. 
            var DeleteFromDelete = listBoxobj.ItemsSource as ICollection<YourDataType>;
            if (DeleteFromDelete != null)
            {
                //this removes the item to be removed from the currently viewing listview.
                DeleteFromDelete.Remove(dataContext);

                //now add the item that was deleted into the other listview.
                var TobeAddedIntoList = secondListBoxobj.ItemsSource as ICollection<YourDataType>;
                if (TobeAddedIntoList != null)
                    TobeAddedIntoList.Add(dataContext);
            }
        }
    }
```